# Set default gateway on HP Procurve switch

Tags: routing, switch

I have an HP procurve switch that *has* routing enabled, that I want to change the default gatway for. Because routing is enabled the "ip default-gateway" command is out.

So now I run:

Bldg1-SVR(config)# ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.0.0.3

but I get the error "Commit failed."

How can I overcome this error?

---

Below are the subnets that this box is routing, and at the top you can see the gateway I want to change.

```
IP Route Entries

  Destination        Gateway         VLAN Type      Sub-Type   Metric     Dist.
  ------------------ --------------- ---- --------- ---------- ---------- -----
  0.0.0.0/0          10.0.0.1        1    static               1          1
  10.0.0.0/24        DEFAULT_VLAN    1    connected            1          0
  10.0.1.0/24        bldg1Left       2    connected            1          0
  10.0.2.0/24        bldg2down       3    connected            1          0
  10.0.3.0/24        bldg2up         4    connected            1          0
  10.0.5.0/24        wireless        6    connected            1          0
  10.0.6.0/24        B3Test          9    connected            1          0
  10.0.7.0/24        b3Prod          10   connected            1          0
  10.0.8.0/24        b2sqa           11   connected            1          0
  10.0.10.0/24       TechSup         12   connected            1          0
  127.0.0.0/8        reject               static               0          0
  127.0.0.1/32       lo0                  connected            1          0
  192.168.1.0/24     10.0.0.2        1    static               1          1
  192.168.10.0/24    10.0.0.2        1    static               1          1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
no ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.0.0.1

ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.0.0.3
```